# typing indication in xmpp chat in iphone

Tags: iphone, xmpp, chat

I am developing chat application using XMPP. Here my problem is, I want to send chat notifications .I tried the fallowing way but not getting correctly.

```
- (void)sendMessage:(id)sender
{   


    NSString *messageStr =messageField.text;
    if([messageStr length] > 0)
    {

         NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
         NSXMLElement *chatStatus=[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"composing" xmlns:xmlns_chatstates];

        [body setStringValue:messageStr];
         NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:jidString];

        [message addChild:chatStatus];
        [message addChild:body];


        [[self xmppStream] sendElement:message];
    }
}
```

I am using above method for sending a message.But it always shows typing notification even i am not typing .can any one help to me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

According to [XEP-0085: Chat State Notifications](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html), you should send another notification saying you've stopped typing, for example `<active/>` or `<paused/>`.

Comment: how to send <active/> or <paused/> notification?